# Is there any possibility to remove ? and = in html?

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, url

I am trying to give pretty url for my html page. I found many answers but they are more related to php. I need to convert this link below,

```
http://localhost/blog.html?id=1
```

to

```
http://localhost/blog/1
```

I have the `.htaccess` file for removing html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Help me to change my url parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you find are perfectly valid for you, since this is independent of any higher level logic like php. These rules operate on the level of the http server.

Anyway, here is a rule to get you started:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?blog$ blog.html?id=%1 [END,QSD]
```

In case you get an http status 500 ("internal server error") using this then chances are that you operate a very only version of the apache http server. You will find a hint about an unsopported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. Try replacing the `END` flag by the older `L` flag, that *probably* will work the same, though this depends a bit on your setup.

Comment: I gave like this->
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?blog$ blog.html?id=&1 [END,QSA]
But it gives me an 404 object not found error and i am using the latest version sir

Comment: That means that either `/blog.html` simply does not exist, or that the rule does not get applied. Where did you put that rule, in the http server's http host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess")?